# The specified type member 'Notes' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a class Student (pseudo code below):

```
public class Student {
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

And a partial class (pseudo code below):

```
public partial class Student {
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }
}
```

Enrollment class:

```
public class Enrollment {
    public int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
}
```

LINQ:

```
var student = dataContext.Student;
var studentEnrollments = student.Join(
                             dataContext.Enrollment,
                             s => s.EnrollmentId,
                             e => e.EnrollmentId,
                             (s, e) => new
                             {
                                 id = s.StudentId,
                                 name = s.FirstName,
                                 course = e.CourseName
                             });
```

Now when I write a link statement, and I want to order by Notes, or Instructions, I get the error:

> The specified type member 'Notes' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Now Notes and Instructions are not columns in the Student table in the database. Is that what is throwing this exception? How can I sort based on these two fields, Notes and Exceptions if I need to?

Comment: That isn't pseudo-code, its just code ;) /pedant

Comment: If the Notes and Exceptions fields aren't in the Employee table, where are they?  Are they in the database at all?  If not, where is their data coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably it's trying to convert your LINQ code into SQL.  It can't do so for those two fields because they're not database fields, hence the error.

Try doing the rest of your query, then calling ToList() on it (forcing the SQL part to execute), and *then* calling OrderBy on the non-database field you want to sort by.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but if those fields are not coming from the database, how will they ever have anything in them (having queried the DB), and hence what would be the point ordering by them or filtering using them?

Comment: @Jamiec, you'd have to ask san that question, not me.